# Printing out an array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, printing

I am printing out an array to a .txt file. I have not discussed the array definition/formulation here, because its complex.

To give a background, its a 2D array and I wish to write the data from the array to another file on my computer. I am using the following code. The problem is I am unable to compile the code and the error points to this section of the code. Could anyone please point out what is wrong in the data implementation with this?

```
   ofstream outFile;
   outFile.open("matrix.txt");

   for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
    ofstream << matrix[i][j];
    }}
   outFile.close();
```

Comment: `outFile << matrix[i]j[j];`

Comment: You have written `ofstream << matrix[i][j]` when you should have written `outFile << matrix[i][j]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [MCVE].   Include the error code in your post.  Your code is perhaps too minimal (though Joe F. noticed the error), perhaps you should include the type of each matrix element (int, float, or instance).

Comment: Please post the needed codes for others to be able to compile it